# How to check if referring URL contains a particular segment?

Tags: jquery, indexing, shopify, referrer

How can I check if the referring URL contains /checkout/ in the second segment?

I want a 'Continue Shopping' button to link differently depending on the previous page the customer has visited.

I'd like to check if the customer has returned to the 'cart' page from the 'checkout' page.

Checkout page url looks like:

'mysite.com.au/checkouts/au/xyz'

I need to check to see if the referrer url contains 'checkout'.

Here is what I've tried.

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf("checkouts") > -1)  {
       $('.js-back').on('click', function(evt) {
        //evt.preventDefault();
        //history.go(-2);
        alert("cart found");
        console.log('It works');
      });
      }
      else {
      $('.js-back').on('click', function(evt) {
        // evt.preventDefault();
        //history.go(-1);
      alert("not found");
      console.log('It not works');
      });
      }
```

Comment: what's the issue you are getting?

Comment: My code doesn’t work. There must be an issue somewhere

Comment: use like this: `if(window.location.href.indexOf("checkouts") > -1) {`

Comment: Isn’t that for the current url not the referencing url?

Comment: yes. any how your refering url will become current url when clicked/opened